# Orbit under Lie group and projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety#Highest_weight_orbits_and_homogeneous_projective_varieties there is a section which says

> Blockquote
>   If G is a semisimple algebraic group (or **Lie group**) and V is a (finite dimensional) highest weight representation of G, then the highest weight space is a point in the projective space P(V) and its orbit under the action of G is a projective algebraic variety. This variety is a (generalized) flag variety, and furthermore, every (generalized) flag variety for G arises in this way.

I am interested in a proof of this statement, especially for the case of Lie groups. Does anyone have a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see: Densities and integration of the notes http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lecnotes/lie2010.pdf